# ABCpdf, render an HTML within a "template": How to add margin?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, abcpdf

I'm trying to render an HTML within a predefined PDF-template (e.g. within a frame.) The template/frame should reach the edges. But the HTML shouldn't do that. So I need some kind of margin for the HTML only. Here is my code so far:

```
var doc = new Doc();
doc.MediaBox.String = "A4";
doc.Rect.String = doc.MediaBox.String;

var id = doc.AddImageUrl(url.ToString());

doc.AddImageDoc("template.pdf", 1, doc.MediaBox);

while (doc.Chainable(id))
{
    doc.Page = doc.AddPage();

    id = doc.AddImageToChain(id);

    doc.AddImageDoc("template.pdf", 1, doc.MediaBox);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= doc.PageCount; i++)
{
    doc.PageNumber = i;
    doc.Flatten();
}
```

I see, that there is a possibility to pass a Rect to `#AddImageDoc`. But I don't have this option for `#AddImageUrl`.

Comment: Did you find the way to add margin to the page?¿ thanks!

Comment: hey guy I have asked here maybe you can help me or just if someone answer me you can get the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I could solve the problem:

First, I set the position and margins of the `doc.Rect`:

```
doc.Rect.Position(15, 15);
doc.Rect.Width = pageWidth - 2*15;
doc.Rect.Height = pageHeight - 2*15;
```

Then I filled the doc with the images from the parsed URL:

```
var id = doc.AddImageUrl(url.ToString());

while (doc.Chainable(id))
{
    doc.Page = doc.AddPage();
    id = doc.AddImageToChain(id);
}
```

After this, I reset the `doc.Rect` to the size of the actual paper (in ma case: A4):

```
doc.Rect.String = "A4";
```

Now I can loop over all pages and add the template to them:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= doc.PageCount; i++)
{
    doc.PageNumber = i;
    doc.AddImageDoc(template, 1, doc.Rect);
    doc.Flatten();
}
```